# Null pointer setting 2d array object method to true

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array which is of objects of the Node class. This is the Node class:

```
public class Node {
private boolean edge;
private int parent;

public Node() {
 edge = false;
    parent = 0;
}

public Node(boolean edge, int parent) {
    this.edge = edge;
    this.parent = parent;
}

public boolean isNode() {
    return edge;
}

public void setNode(boolean node) {
    this.edge = node;
}

public int getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(int parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
}
```

And this is my 2d array:

```
private Node[][] adjMatrix = new Node[x][y];
```

In a method named addEdge I am trying to set the node at the points i,j in the array to true.

```
public void addEdge(int i, int j) {
        adjMatrix[i][j].setNode(true);
        adjMatrix[j][i].setNode(true);
}
```

However I am getting a nullpointerexception on this line and I do not know how to fix it.

```
adjMatrix[i][j].setNode(true);
```

I assume it's a simple answer that I haven't been able to find the answer to because I have been looking for awhile. So any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `adjMatrix[i][j]` is null => you need, somewhere, to initialise it with a non null value: `adjMatrix[i][j] = new Node(...);`.

Comment: Yes sorry the answer was obvious. I previously had had a 2 dimensional array of booleans and as they are primitive types I did not have to initialize them, when I then changed the array to one of objects I forgot about then having to initialize them :) Thanks for the answers everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not instantiated your `Nodes` inside the list.

```
Node[][] adjMatrix = new Node[x][y];
```

The above statement only initializes your array and does not instantiate the element in it.

You need to terate through the matrix using for loop, and for each element do: -

```
adjMatrix[i][j] = new Node();
```

You need to do this before using your matrix elements..

Answer (score 0):

The array is initialized to null, you have to allocate instances of Node to fill the array.